# How to convert number mixed with character to integer in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert a columns where the elements have a type liked number mixed with character, and I want to convert the column to `Integer` type.

`Input:`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['Q001','Q021']})
```

`Output:`

```
    id
0   Q001
1   Q021
```

`Expected`:

```
    id  idInt
0   Q001    1
1   Q021    21
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or use `pd.Series.str.replace` with regex of `'\D+'` being replaced with `''` in each string:

```
df['idInt']=df['id'].str.replace('\D+','').astype(int)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
     id  idInt
0  Q001      1
1  Q021     21
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by regex `\d+` with casting to integers:

```
df['idInt'] = df['id'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
print (df)
     id  idInt
0  Q001      1
1  Q021     21
```

Difference of answers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['12Q001','Q021']})

#remove non numeric
df['idInt1']=df['id'].str.replace('\D+','').astype(int)
#extract first numeric 
df['idInt2'] = df['id'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
print (df)
       id  idInt1  idInt2
0  12Q001   12001      12
1    Q021      21      21
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (more obscure) option and less generic than the above regex-based approaches:

`df["idIint"] = df["id"].str.rpartition("Q",expand=False).str[-1].astype(int)`

Which procudes:

```
     id  idIint
0  Q001       1
1  Q021      21
```